# Expected distance of the first and second nearest person to one of the 2 cars on a circle road with uniformly distributed locations

Tags: probability, expected-value, operations-research

let $X=\min(x_{11},x_{12},...,x_{1n},x_{21},x_{22},...,x_{2n})$，such as，$X=x_{1k}$
and
$Y=\min(x_{21},x_{22},...,x_{2,k-1},x_{2,k+1},...,x_{2n})$

and $\forall x_{ij}$ is i.i.d, uniform random variable on [0,1].

so we can get X's cdf which is $F_X(x)=1-(1-x)^{2n}$ and its pdf $f_X(x)=2n(1-x)^{2n-1}$。then $E(X)=1/(2n+1)$

similarly，$F_Y(y)=1-(1-y)^{n-1}$，$f_Y(y)=(n-1)(1-y)^{n-2}$。then $E(Y)=1/n$.

but obviously $Y＞=X$ so i want to know how to get $E(Y|Y＞=X)$ under these conditions.

And the real question is that given a circle road and its length is 1,and car’s direction must be clockwise.Assume that there are n persons and 2 cars uniformly distributed on this circle.let S(n,2) be the expected average optimal matching distance,and can we get the closed form of S(n,2).

I found that if we calculate the distance matrix,and just find the minimum value in the matrix,then delete the corresponding row and column,then find the minimum Value among the remaining elements ,and the sum of these two operations is the optimal matching distance. That’s why I raised this question.

Now I realize there is another issue. Assuming there are two cars with coordinates $x_1$ and $x_2$,and two people with coordinates $y_1$ and $y_2$,because the cars can only move clockwise, the distance between a car $x$ and a person $y$ depends on whether $x<=y$. If $x<=y$,the distance is $y−x$;otherwise, it is $1+y−x$.

This allows us to obtain a $2×2$ distance matrix. Initially, I thought that the four elements in the distance matrix were all independent, but now I am not so sure.

Comment: $Y=X$ with probability $\frac12$ and $Y>X$ with probability $\frac12$, so you should not say "obviously $Y\gt X$".  In addition, one of your statements for the distributions of $X$ and $Y$ may have an off-by-one error.

Comment: It is not true that $Y > X$ always. I think it would be obvious that $Y \geq X$.

Comment: Note:  it is true that we only have $Y≥X$ a priori, but $P(Y=X)=0$ so the distinction doesn't change much.  But I misread the problem initially...I thought you were simply asking about the expected value of the second least element, but then $Y$ should have considered the $x_{1j}$.  And why would you delete $x_{2k}$?

Comment: @lulu: I would have thought $P(Y=X)=\frac{n}{2n}=\frac12$

Comment: @Henry I may be misreading.  I thought that $Y$ was meant to be the second least element.  But it looks like it's something else.  I don't understand why the OP specifies $x_{1k}$ as the minimum, but then removes $x_{2k}$.  I figured the OP was deleting the minimum.

Comment: @user1180847  Can you edit for clarity?  From what you have written, you identify the minimum value as $x_{1k}$ but then delete $x_{2k}$ from the list, in addition to all the $x_{1j}$.  Is that what you intended?  In any case:  you expect all the gaps to be $\frac 1{2n+1}$ so once the rules are sorted out you can pretty much read off the expected minimum of a subset.

Comment: @Henry you're right,theoretically Y >= X.

Comment: @lulu sorry for that……the real question is a matching problem，that is to say n persons and 2 car，and $x_{ij}$is the distance. So if we assume $X = x_{1k}$,we have to delete $x_{2k}$ because person k was matched

Comment: Ok, so then you have deleted the known minimum (at $x_{ik}$) along with all the other $x_{1j}$ and then you have $n-1$ chosen at random from the non-minimums.  Now, knowing that you expect the $i^{th}$ least element to be $\frac i{2n+1}$ you can get the desired expectation.

Comment: I think the distances of the persons to the second care after assigning the first car will not change. Is that true?

Comment: @lulu sorry but I can’t understand that the $i^{th}$ least element is $i/(2n+1)$ , it is just random, and $x_{1k}$ is just an example,the minimum value may be any variable.

Comment: @Amir yeah you are right.the distance will not change

Comment: The expectation is $\frac i{2n+1}$.  You expect each gap to have size $\frac 1{2n+1}$.  And it makes a difference if you are removing the minimum or not.  The way you have written it, the minimum is at $x_{1k}$ and you have removed that (along with $x_{2k}$ for whatever reason).  If you meant something else, please edit your post for clarity.

Comment: @lulu thank you very much,I need to think about it some more

Comment: Nice question! I have a solution for it. May I know the source of the original problem?

Comment: @Amir yeah,I have to write an essay including such a question about OR,this is the source.haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us first clearly define the random variables. We have

$$X=\min (A_1,\dots, A_n, B_1,\dots, B_n)=\min (A_\zeta, B_\zeta)$$

where $\zeta$ is a random variable taking values in $\{1,\dots,n\}$. Then, we can define

$$
Y= \begin{cases}
      \min (B_1,\dots,B_{\zeta-1}, B_{\zeta+1},\dots, B_n)& \quad X=A_\zeta  \\
      \min (A_1,\dots,A_{\zeta-1}, A_{\zeta+1},\dots, A_n)& \quad X=B_\zeta.
    \end{cases}
$$

As each car can move **only clockwise**, each of $A_i, B_i, i=1,\dots,n$ is uniformly distributed over $(0,1)$. When, each car is allowed to **move in both directions**, each of $\, A_i, B_i, i=1,\dots,n \,$ follows the distribution of $Z=\min (U, 1-U)$  with $U \sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$, where we can show $Z \sim \text{Uniform} \left (0,\frac{1}{2} \right)$.

We always have $Y \ge X$, so

$$\mathbb E (Y | Y \ge X)= \mathbb E (Y).$$

Because of the symmetry, we can see that

$$\mathbb E (Y) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2n} \mathbb E \big (Y \big | X=A_i \big )+\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2n} \mathbb E \big (Y \big | X=B_i \big )= \mathbb E \big (Y \big | X=A_1).$$

The expectation $\mathbb E \big (Y \big | X=A_1)$ can be computed as

$$\mathbb E (Y | X=A_1) =\int_0^1 f_{A_1}(a) \mathbb E \bigg (Y \big | X=A_1, A_1=a   \bigg) \text{d}t \, \text{d}a=\\ \int_0^1 1 \times \mathbb E (\min (B_2,\dots, B_n) \big | A_2,\dots, A_n, B_1,\dots, B_n > a)  \text{d}a=\\ \int_0^1 \int_a^1 \mathbb P (\min (B_2,\dots, B_n)>t \big | A_2,\dots, A_n, B_1,\dots, B_n > a)  \text{d}t \, \text{d}a= \\ \int_0^1 \int_a^1 \frac{(1-t)^{n-2}(1-a)^{n}}{(1-a)^{2n-1}} \text{d}t \, \text{d}a =\frac{1}{n-1}.$$

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151927/discussion-on-answer-by-amir-expected-distance-of-the-first-and-second-nearest-p); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.